# MySQL UPDATE ranking query works locally, not on server

Tags: mysql, sql-update, ranking

I have a sports pools database with tables:

- pools (id, name, sport, type, season, startRound, endRound)
- entries (poolId, userId, entryId, poolPoints, poolRank)
- picks (poolId, userId, entryId, round, pick, pickResult, pickPoints)

I can query and sum the pickPoints into poolPoints by pool/user/entry. I was then using the query shown below to update the poolRank based on poolPoints highest to lowest. I am 95% certain it worked both locally and on my server, previously. Now it does not work on the server and I can't figure out why.

Queries:

```
-- get current round and set as variable
SELECT round FROM hockey_games WHERE gameDate <= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY gameDate DESC LIMIT 1 INTO @round;

-- rank pick'em players (overall)
UPDATE mop_survivor_entries b 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT poolId, userId, entryId, poolPoints, rank FROM (
    SELECT poolId, userId, entryId, poolPoints, 
    @curRank := IF(@prevPool != poolId, 1, IF(@prevRank = poolPoints, @curRank, @incRank)) AS rank,
    @incRank := IF(@prevPool != poolId, 2, @incRank + 1), 
    @prevRank := poolPoints,
    @prevPool := poolId
    FROM mop_pools c, mop_survivor_entries e, 
    (SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @prevPool := 604, @incRank := 1) r
    WHERE c.id = e.poolId
    AND sport = 'hockey'
    AND type = 'pickem'
    AND season = 2017
    AND startRound <= @round
    AND endRound >= @round
    ORDER BY poolId ASC, poolPoints DESC
    ) s
  ) a ON b.poolId = a.poolId AND b.userId = a.userId AND b.entryId = a.entryId 
SET poolRank = rank;
```

I thought it might have something to do with my user-defined variables resetting but research isn't turning up much in the way of answers.

I tried running the queries through PHP and with phpMyAdmin with same (no change) results.

There is a slight difference in MySQL versions. Local 5.6.3; server 5.5.58 ... but again, feel it did work previously. Appreciate any help someone can give.

Comment: is there anny error on the server?

Comment: No, no error. It just returns 0 rows affected.

Comment: Then the data could be already updated.. a UPDATE that doesn't effect anny rows will return a `0 rows affected` "warning"

Comment: Right, but it is not updated for proper ranking. If I run on identical database locally I get response: Query OK, 17 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 22  Changed: 17  Warnings: 0